# Apache error: AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run some php codes on wampserver 2.4 but every time I try to access the file on localhost I got blank pages. I have already tried all the things I found on this site (80 port, modify httpconfig) but they didn't work. When checked Apache log errors, I got the following messages. I've working for hours on this. So your help would be really aprreciated. thanks in advance.
In the following the php codes:

```
 php
 <?php
    ini_set(\'display_errors\', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ;

    try {
    $response = array();

    $username="root";
    $pass="";
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $username, $pass);
    $name = "aina";
    $email = "luaina.mada";
    $mobile = "0324230671";


     $result=$dbh->query("INSERT INTO students(`Name`,`Email`,`Mobile`)      
      VALUES ('$name','$email','$mobile')");
     if($result){
        $response['value']=1;

     }else{
        $response['value']=0;
    }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Erreur !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
    }




   ?>
```

[image: Error]

```
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5564:tid 380] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3028 
[Wed Apr 10 14:05:26.457486 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3028:tid 312] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads. 
[Wed Apr 1014:06:56.344843 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5564:tid 380] AH00422:
Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
```

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.